# Ray and rectangle intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

How can I check whether a ray intersects a rectangle $(A,B,C,D)$ and solve for the distance from the ray's starting point to the point where the ray intersects the rectangle.

The ray starts from $(x,y)$ and have an angle of $θ$ apart from y-axis

[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otQ2A.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want the intersection with the rectangle border (which will be one or two points) or do you want the intersection with the rectangular area (which will be a line segment)?

Comment: Check answers here. I don’t think rectangle and parallelogram are fundamentally different.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142414/ray-parallelogram-intersection-in-2d